# May I know how to tranfer files from host machine(Ubuntu) to a virtual machine(windows 10)?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization, file-sharing

I want to transfer file from my host OS (ubuntu 22.04) to a virtual machine (Windows 10).
I am using KVM to run Windows 10. I have tried so much but didn't found a way. So i though that someone from this platform can help me.
I will be waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working with VMs since 2012 and hopefully could answer your problem.

See first you might have to install VirtualBox Guest Additions on your Win10 VM. This allows you to access the shared folder on your Ubuntu host machine.

Then create a shared folder on your Ubuntu host machine. You can do this by going to **VirtualBox > Settings > Shared Folders** and adding a new shared folder.

Open your Win10 VM and go to **Devices > Shared Folders > Shared Folders Settings**

Click on the “Add” button to add a new shared folder. In the “Folder Path” field, enter the path to the shared folder on your Ubuntu host machine. In the “Folder Name” field, enter a name for the shared folder.

You can now transfer files between your Ubuntu host machine and Windows 10 virtual machine by copying and pasting them to/from the shared folder.

In short -

Launch VirtualBox, then:

—Open Devices > Shared Folders > Shared Folders Settings.
— Click +, then in Folder Path, click the arrow and select Other.
— Browse for the folder you plan to share, and click Select Folder.
— In Add Share, give the share a name you can use in both operating systems.
— Check Auto-mount and Make permanent, then OK.

From the guest OS, you'll find the share set up in the usual location for network shares.

And I think simple drag and drop would also work.